# How can I change the type pydantic parses according to a value in the parsed dictionary?

Tags: python, pydantic

I would like pydantic to choose the model to use for parsing the input dependent on the input value. Is this possible?

### MVCE

I have a pydantic model which looks similar to this one:

```py
from typing import List, Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Animal(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: Literal["mamal", "bird"]


class Bird(Animal):
    max_eggs: int


class Mamal(Animal):
    max_offspring: int


class Config(BaseModel):
    animals: List[Animal]


cfg = Config.parse_obj(
    {
        "animals": [
            {"name": "eagle", "type": "bird", "max_eggs": 3},
            {"name": "Human", "type": "mamal", "max_offspring": 3},
        ]
    }
)

print(cfg.json(indent=4))
```

gives

```
{
    "animals": [
        {
            "name": "eagle",
            "type": "bird"
         <-- missing max_offspring, as "Animal" was used instead of Bird
        },
        {
            "name": "Human",
            "type": "mamal"
          <-- missing max_offspring, as "Animal" was used instead of Mamal
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that I could set `Config.extra="allow"` in `Animal`, but that is not what I want. I would like pydantic to see that a dictionary with `'type': 'mamal'` should use the `Mamal` model to parse.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add concrete literals to every child class to differentiate and put them in `Union` from more to less specific order. Like so:

```
class Animal(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: str


class Bird(Animal):
    type: Literal["bird"]
    max_eggs: int


class Mamal(Animal):
    type: Literal["mamal"]
    max_offspring: int

class Config(BaseModel):
    animals: List[Union[Bird, Mamal, Animal]]  # From more specific to less
```